# how to cumulate contextMenu and drag&drop?

Tags: android, drag-and-drop, android-contextmenu

I would like some implementation advice combining context menu and drag&drop in a recyclerview (but I don't think it's specific to this context).

By definition, the context menu opens with a long press. But this is also the case for drag&drop since you have to press and hold and drag.

So how do we best combine both?
Knowing that I already have an action on the single tap and that I find double tap is not adapted to one or the other.

Maybe I'm asking the impossible, but then, you, in this situation, what do you do?

The question concerns more the good practices than the technical aspect of the implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without solution, I finally replaced contextMenu by popupMenu opened with a button at the right of the item and simple tap became double tap. Like that, I can conserve Drag&Drop.